# How is 'instruction' different from 'command'? 'list' from 'array'?

Tags: terminology

For specifically 'list' and 'array', does the difference depend on the programming language, or is it universal in the field of computer science?
Im new to CS, and for some reason I only hear 'list' mentioned in Python, and 'array' in Java, never heard 'array' in Java or 'list' in Python. Does this imply difference in implementation? or just in naming?

Comment: Python has both lists and arrays, which behave differently. And most of the time, when arrays are mentioned in a Python context, numpy arrays are meant (not the ones from the standard library). So yes, there is definitely some context dependence if you're talking about a specific language.

Comment: @Evert this question is a _very_ poor fit for Programmers - it would be quickly voted down and closed over there, see http://meta.programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/6483/why-was-my-question-closed-or-down-voted/6490#6490 Recommended reading: **[What goes on Programmers.SE? A guide for Stack Overflow](http://meta.programmers.stackexchange.com/q/7182/31260)**

Answer (score 0):

It may depend on the actual programming language and/or platform... but in a more general term:

- An array is a set of contiguous memory that holds elements of the same type in a "packed" way.
- A list is a set of items, addressed by pointers (or similar mechanisms) that link those items. Not necessarily contiguous in memory

This is a very general broad description... different languages and platforms may implement things differently. In some, an array and a list may be indistinguishable.

More likely, an array has a fixed size (to resize it you have to create a new array and copy the original contents to it), and can't have "holes". A list has (normally) dynamic capacity, and you can insert or remove items at any point without destroying the original list. But again, these are implementation details that may vary depending on the programming language you use.

Comment: I disagree.  That is a *very* C-centric way of looking at it.  C# "List" objects are what you would call "vector" in C++.

Comment: @MartinBonner I tried (not sure if succeeded) to give a broad description that works for many languages, but yeah, it's impossible not to bias somewhere. Language designers can label things however they want :-)

Comment: How about C++ or Java? I heard they are the most popular/standard languages. Are 'list', 'array' and 'vector' different in those languages?